# How do others keep a clipart repository up to date?

Tags: deployment

We have a clipart library with our application, its recently grown in size (based on marketings feedback) to be 2GB of data.

The application installer is now 1GB and really a bit unmanageable for some of the countries we distribute to.

What solutions would you use install and keep a library like that up to date?

Comment: What does "unmanageable" mean, how do you "distribute" it, and in what way is it country-specific?

Comment: By "unmanageable" I mean that a single 1GB download is considered a bad thing in some parts of Italy or Lithuania.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility may be to let customers select subsets (some/all/none) of the library.

Comment: However the installer would still be 1GB, the initial download of a 1GB file is a concern to me.

Comment: For really big optional components, you might want to consider secondary downloads.  Present a picklist & have the installer or the app bring down only the selected optional library portions. For example, we use Installshield for our installers. When there are component updates, IS gives us a list & we bring down the things we're interested in & ignore the rest.

Comment: Microsoft has done the same with software updates: it lists them, explains them, says how big they are, and lets the users decide which ones they want.